# How i can build the route?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, datatables

Hi im building laravel app, i have a tables with messages and i want to display the data with datatables. In my index view the data are visible and the sort, pagination e searchbar of datatables work fine, i also added the edit and delete button, i started working on the delete button but i have a route problem.
this my route file web.php

```
Route::middleware('auth')
    ->namespace('Admin')
    ->name('admin.') 
    ->prefix('admin') 
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
        Route::resource('/user', 'UserController');/* ->except(['edit', 'update']); */
        Route::resource('/user/{user:id}/messages', 'MessagesController');

    });

    Route::get('messages', 'Admin\MessagesController@getMessages')->name('get.messages');

    Auth::routes();
```

the function in the MessagesController who return me the messages in the datatables

```
public function getMessages()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return DataTables::of(Message::query())
            ->addColumn('action', function ($message) use ($user) {
                return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="' . $message->id . '"  class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-modal-' . $message->id . '"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i> Modifica</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger deleteMessage" data-id="' . $message->id . '" data-user="' . auth()->user()->id . '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal-' . $message->id . '"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Elimina</a>
            ';
            })
            ->setRowClass('{{$id % 2 == 0 ? "alert-success" : "alert-danger"}}')
            ->setRowId(function ($message) {
                return $message->id;
            })
            ->setRowAttr(['align' => 'center'])

            ->make(true);
    }
```

and this is my jquery code for delete the record in the datatables

```
$('body').on('click', '.deleteMessage', function() {

            var id = $(this).data("id");
            confirm("Are You sure want to delete this Post!");

            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",

                url: "{{ route('admin.messages.destroy', ['user' => auth()->user()->id]) }}/" +
                    id,
                success: function(data) {
                    table.draw();
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log('Error:', data);
                }
            });

        });
```

i want the code to delete the record i choose in the datatables but i get this error
Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.messages.destroy] [URI: admin/user/{user}/messages/{message}]. (View: C:\Users\ficus\Desktop\Progetti\ArgostudioADV\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/user/1/messages
someone can find out how i can build the url in the delete function?

i did the change @aynber suggest to me and its worked, i have the vista with the record now, but now i have another problem, when i press the delete button the pop up show i submit but it give me 405 error and the message still there, but if i reload the page the view give me the successful message of record delete and it disappear in the db too, any clue for this?
it is like the function never go in the success but it delete the record because we call the destroy route

Comment: You want to delete 1 message right ? You need a route with a message id in it. I don't see one in your routes file.

Comment: `admin.messages.destroy` also requires a message ID. Since you're using javascript to pass the id, you can't use the `route` command to build the route, since `route` is PHP and will be done before the page is sent to the user. You'll need to just build it yourself. You can still use `{{ auth()->user()->id }}` to get the user ID.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define the resource route correctly.

resource route

```
Route::resource('user.messages', MessagesController::class);
```

message delelte link

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger deleteMessage" data-route="{{ route('admin.messages.destroy', [auth()->id(), $message->id]) }}"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal-' . $message->id . '"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Elimina</a>
```

#js code

```
$('body').on('click', '.deleteMessage', function() {
        var route = $(this).data("route");
        confirm("Are You sure want to delete this Post!");
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{csrf_token()}}" },
            type: "DELETE",
            url: route,
            success: function(data) {
                table.draw();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    });
```